# Prism: re-use view instance when navigating

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

## Summary

When a button is pressed, call RequestNavigate which takes `MainView` from `ContentRegion` and inserts it into `DialogContentRegion`. Currently, on RequestNavigate, a new instance of `MainView` is inserted into `DialogContentRegion`.

## Description

Here is a diagram that synthesizes what I'm looking for.

[image: Diagram]

- `ContentRegion` is the main region and contains the `MainView`.
- `DialogView` contains the region `DialogContentRegion` in a ContentControl.
- `IDialogService` is used in the `PinModuleCommand` of the `MainViewModel` to show the dialog.
- In `DialogViewModel`, `RegionManager.RequestNavigate()` is used to display view in `DialogContentRegion` when the dialog is opened.
- `IContainerRegistry` is used to register the views.

```cs
public void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
{
    containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<MainView>();
    containerRegistry.RegisterDialog<DialogView>();
}
```

> The same RegionManager is used throughout.

- `DialogView.xaml`

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="Infrastructure.Views.DialogView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Infrastructure.Views"
             xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/" xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <ContentControl x:Name="_contentControl" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="DialogContentRegion"/>
</UserControl>
```

- `DialogView.xaml.cs`

```cs
public partial class DialogView : UserControl
{
    IRegionManager _regionManager;
    public DialogView(IRegionManager regionManager)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _regionManager = regionManager;

        if (!_regionManager.Regions.ContainsRegionWithName("DialogContentRegion"))
        {
            RegionManager.SetRegionManager(_contentControl, _regionManager);
        }
    }
}
```

- `DialogViewModel.cs`

```cs
public class DialogViewModel : BindableBase, IDialogAware
    {
        IRegionManager _regionManager;

        private string _title;
        public string Title
        {
            get { return _title; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _title, value); }
        }

        private string _view;
        public string View
        {
            get { return _view; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _view, value); }
        }

        public PinDialogViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager)
        {
            _regionManager = regionManager;
        }

        public event Action<IDialogResult> RequestClose;

        public bool CanCloseDialog()
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void OnDialogClosed()
        {
            _regionManager.Regions.Remove("DialogContentRegion");
        }

        public void OnDialogOpened(IDialogParameters parameters)
        {
            View = parameters.GetValue<string>("view");

            if (_regionManager.Regions.ContainsRegionWithName("DialogContentRegion"))
            {
                _regionManager.RequestNavigate("DialogContentRegion", View);
            }
        }
    }
```

- `MainViewModel.cs`

```cs
public class MainViewModel : BindableBase, INavigationAware
{
    private DelegateCommand _pinModuleComamnd;
    public DelegateCommand PinModuleCommand =>
        _pinModuleComamnd ?? (_pinModuleComamnd = new DelegateCommand(ExecutePinModuleCommand));

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        
    }

    void ExecutePinModuleCommand()
    {
        _dialogService.Show(nameof(PinDialogView), new DialogParameters { { "view", "MainView" } }, DialogCallback);
    }

    private void DialogCallback(IDialogResult dialogResult)
    {

    }

    public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationContext navigationContext)
    {
        
    }

    public bool IsNavigationTarget(NavigationContext navigationContext)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationContext navigationContext)
    {
        
    }
}
```

### Expected behavior

When navigating to `MainView` in the `DialogContentRegion`, the view instance in the dialog should be the same as in the main window.

### Actual behavior

A new view instance is created.

### Additional information

I have observed that on navigating in the dialog, `IsNavigationTarget()` is never called in `MainViewModel`. Why is that?

Comment: You could register the view model as a singleton. 
 For example: `containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<DialogViewModel>()`

Comment: @Joe that doesn't seem to work. A new view instance is still created.

Comment: A few questions:  Does the view-model actually get created?  I assume so but want to be sure.  Also, why do you have that region manager code in the constructor of `DialogView` ?  You should not need it.   Try specifying `DialogViewModel` as a second generic argument when you register the view.  In my code I register the view model as the singleton first and then register the view with view-model.  I also overrode the application's `ConfigureViewModelLocator` function but I don't think you should need that...

Comment: I am re-reading your post and I see I misunderstood you.  `RegisterForNavigation` wants a view and a either implies a view model (via naming conventions) or lets you specify one as the second argument.  I was assuming you wanted to make `ContentRegion` contain an instance of `DialogView` backed by an instance `DialogViewModel`.  And that you wanted one and only one of these.  So that you would navigate it there.  But your nested region confuses me

Comment: @Joe I made some edits. I hope that this clarifies some of the questions that you had.

Comment: So you are trying to take an existing prism view that is already showing and then move it to inside a dialog?  Well  I will freely admit I have no idea if that is even possible.

Comment: @Joe yep, that is what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Not sure if this will be of any help but it seems relevant:  https://prismlibrary.com/docs/wpf/region-navigation/controlling-view-lifetime.html